# Send data to another JavaScript file from a JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, c#, html, ajax, model-view-controller

I want to see the information of this admin in the panel when admin enters the panel. But there are more than one admin on the system. Therefore, I need to find the administrator who logs in to the system according to the mail entered from the login page. When I click submit button, I need to send this mail to landing_page.js file from admin.js file. **How can I send this data from one JavaScript file to another JavaScript file**

İ’m using MVC. İ’m sending and receiving data using C#. And I use ajax for this . And disabling the form’s page refresh feature using ‘return false’.

admin.cshtml

```
$("[name='login_form']").click(function () {
    $.post("/Home/AdminLogin", { email: $("#admin_email").val() }, function (data) {
        //// send the information of admin to _LayoutPage.cshtml
        var fl = data.xfirst_name;
        var ln = data.xlast_name;

        /*if password is correct*/
        if ($("#admin_password").val() == data.passwrd) {
            /*go to Users_Panel.cshtml*/
            window.location.href = "/home/dashboard";
            /**/
        }/**/
    })
    .fail(function (data) {
        alert("Server Error");
    });
});
```

I need to send 'fl' and 'ln' to landing-page.js

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET? Can you please provide more information on the technologies you are using?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using ASP.NET (because of the .cshtml), then take a look at this tutorial: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Simple-User-Login-Form-example-in-ASPNet.aspx.

Basically, with a login form like this:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Login ID = "Login1" runat = "server" OnAuthenticate= "ValidateUser"></asp:Login>
</form>
```

You can call the method "ValidateUser" when the user clicks LogIn. This function looks like:

```
protected void ValidateUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    [your logic to get user information goes here]

    FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage(); //Redirect to the page here
}
```

Please provide more information on the technologies you wish to use.